# Visit Northern Ontario from Toronto without a car?

Tags: transportation, canada, buses, toronto, ontario

If  I wish to visit the towns of Northern Ontario starting from Toronto on a budget and I do not drive a car, what are my best options?
Greyhound?
Is there anything else? Like an organised car pool/shuttle service that runs between Toronto and some country side towns in Ontario?

Comment: I've never hitchhiked to Northern Ontario, but maybe it's possible.  First, read ["Hitchhiking#Safety"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitchhiking#Safety) on Wikipedia.  Next, try a Google search for [\[ hitchhiking northern ontario \]](http://www.google.ca/search?q=hitchhiking+northern+ontario).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best bet for public transport access to the Ontario North is [Ontario Northland](http://www.ontarionorthland.ca/en/index.php/passenger-trains-and-buses/). They run scheduled buses from Toronto to the north, including Temagami (but not Hiawatha, wherever that is).

It is quite a trip, stopping at various small towns you won't get to otherwise. If you want to get to the real remote areas your best bet is the Polar Bear Express train to Moosonee - it's as remote as you can get without flying, which I assume is outside your budget.

Answer (score 12):

It depends what you define as Northern Ontario and how much you want to see. Some places (Moosonee and Moose Factory for example) are train only. Many are bus only. You can fly to Sudbury on a regularly scheduled commercial flight. Heck, some people might consider Peterborough or Barrie to be northern, and you can take Go Transit (commuter trains and buses) there. You might take the train (Via or Go) to a "gateway town" and then the bus  from there. I find bus service to be pretty sketchy - there might be one bus a day, and it's not particularly cheap. You are also likely to run into a bit of "can't get there from here" where you have to plan your route carefully.

Comment: Well...I was looking to go to Hiawatha,ON. And also Temagami. And flying to Sudbury will not be cheap.I am looking for cheap options :)

Comment: Where is "Hiawatha"? Google only found me a lake with that name.

Comment: ...or a place south of Peterborough, which isn't really North.

Comment: You must have a reason for wanting to go to Hiawatha. Can you not ask that person how to get there? Assuming you mean the one near HornePayne, it's a LONG way from everywhere.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your budget the service that would be the least hassle, and the most flexible would probably be bus. The train doesn't stop too many places up there unless your'e going into the interior on Ontario Northland (and that's only because you can choose where to stop), and VIA isn't the cheapest option out there.

Comment: except greyhound, is there any other cheap bus service?

Comment: Depends on your definition of cheap I suppose.

Comment: Ontario Northland runs buses.

Comment: I think that, on VIA Rail's train called "The Canadian", there's a way to request for the train to stop at any mile marker of your choice, both when leaving the train, and I think also when getting on the train. There need not be any station there. Phone VIA Rail for more information. Does anyone here know more information?

Comment: @unforgettableid Thats' news to me The Canadian outside of Northern Ontario and the BC Interior is decently populated. Well for Canada that is.

Comment: @unforgettableid See https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1866/2509