# Map of ViaRail train stations in Canada

Tags: trains, canada, maps, train-stations, via-rail

Is there a map of all stations served by ViaRail (passenger train carrier in Canada)? I could find [a vague map](http://www.viarail.ca/en/explore-our-destinations/trains) of their main destinations, but I am looking for a more precise map.

I would like to know, in particular between Toronto and Ottawa, where the train stops and what community and attractions are nearby a station.

Is there a map/multiple maps showing the towns served by ViaRail stations?

Comment: Train stops along some lines are too densely spaced to be visible on a map showing all railway lines in Canada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a map as such, but [Wikipedia has a list of ViaRail routes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Via_Rail_routes).

Then when you click one of the routes, for example - the [Ocean route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_(train)), you can see on the right a list of every single town stopped at along the route.

On the [Corridor routes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corridor_(Via_Rail)) it actually has a 'map' (diagram) of [the stations along this route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CorridorVia.svg) including between Toronto and Ottawa.

Remember, if necessary it is also possible to [disembark between stations on ViaRail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1866/101) if you give 48 hours notice on certain routes.

Comment: Note that disembarking between stations is limited to some routes (especially not on their busier Toronto-Quebec route).

Answer (score 4):

On the [Schedules](http://www.viarail.ca/en/plan-your-trip/customize-your-train-schedule) page, you can download PDFs of the schedules for specific routes. If you open the one for Toronto, Kingston, Ottawa, you can see all of the stations on that route:

- Toronto
- Guildwood
  -Oshawa
- Port Hope
- Cobourg
- Trenton Jct.
- Belleville
- Napanee
- Kingston
- Gananoque
- Brockville
- Smiths Falls
- Fallowfield
- Ottawa

You could then use the [Stations](http://www.viarail.ca/en/explore-our-destinations/stations/list) page to get more details. (This page gets you the list, but not the map, you've asked for.) However the details for each station are quite poor - you can see where it is, and that's about it.

Now to keep going I need to know what you mean by "are accessible by public transport". Say that one of these small towns has a little bus route. Does that make that small town meet your needs? If so, great, the station page will tell you how to contact that local public transportation authority. Or do you need to get to them by public transport from somewhere specific, such as YYZ airport or Toronto's Union Station?

Assuming you want to reach the line from Toronto, you will want stations that are shared with [GO](http://gotransit.com/), the commuter rail line. Toronto Union, Guildwood, and Oshawa qualify. (You can't see this on their web site, it is just a thing I know.) Alternatively, stations that are easy to reach by TTC - pretty much this means Union. If you want to reach Cobourg or Belleville by some other means such as a bus (Greyhound, Megabus, whoever is still in business), then you will have to drill a little further into the details about each station and set to work on the websites of those bus companies. I predict you will not enjoy that process.

Comment: Sorry, by public transport, I meant the train, i.e. I just want to see what communities are accessible by train and consequently by public transport. Thanks for your answer, I was a bit disappointed by the list of stations because it is not ordered by distance from Toronto/Ottawa, but only alphabetically. However the pdf schedules are a great resource.